# Spark Scala: how to force Spark to recompute some results (not to use its cache)

Tags: scala, caching, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark and I'm surprised that some results are not recomputed although I didn't (at least I didn't want to) cache them, i.e. I have to restart sbt to see the updated value.

Here is the relevant snippet of code:

```
val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map(
    "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://dbHost:5432/tests?user=simon&password=password",
    "dbtable" -> "events")
).load()

val cached = df.cache()

val tariffs = cached.map(row => row.getAs[Int](2))
```

If I print `tariffs.toDF().mean()` I get the correct average but if I change my code to :

```
val tariffs = cached.map(row => 0)
```

I don't see the new average `(0)` until I restart sbt. How to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve with `.map(row => 0)`. You just create a new `RDD`, why should it modify anything? How do you inspect it?

Comment: I don't try to achieve anything, it is just to show that the average of a RDD[Int] of 0 is not 0 but the average computed before with the real values (i.e. tariffs.toDF().mean() output 17.18 instead of 0) until I restart sbt.

Comment: Try maybe use `unpersist()` to remove it from cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see your entire code so I cannot answer with certainty but, if the following code produces the same output, you should file a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/spark

```
println(cached.map(row => row.getInt(2)).toDF().mean().collect(0))
println(cached.map(row => 0).toDF().mean().collect(0))
```

If, however, they produce different output then very likely there was a problem with your REPL session.

More generally, to remove the effects of caching, use

```
cached.unpersist()
```